# Достаточная причина отказаться что-либо делать, одним-двумя словами?

Tags: одним-словом

Как можно назвать обстоятельства, связанные с определенным действием, которые остановят любого человека в здравом уме от его выполнения? Скорее всего - связанные с угрозой жизни и здоровья, когда выполнение подобных действий называют безрассудством.

Например, этим будет названа жара, говоря о забеге на 250 км по пустыне.

**UPD:** Пояснение про пример с забегом: подобные соревнования проводятся в условиях экстремальной жары и со строгими ограничениями по экипировке. Неподготовленный человек сказал бы, что участие в таких соревнованиях - безрассудство, потому что ... Еще один пример - ныряние на задержке дыхания на глубину 100 м, это возможно, но безрассудно, потому что ...  Т.е. хочется субъективно охарактеризовать обстоятельства, останавливающие одних, и не останавливающие других. Такие обстоятельства, в которых "обычный" человек не окажется по собственной воле.

Есть ли такое слово?

Comment: Is this an English equivalent to the Russian expression you're looking for: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_on_the_Clapham_omnibus ?

Comment: @Quassnoi This is close, but what I am looking for is of a more general sense, not limited to a law, and should preferably describe the conditions, and not the subject. However, do you know the Russian equivalent to "Man on the Clapham omnibus"?

Comment: Quassnoi, я правда не понял - причем тут это... Это какая-то идиома на тему такой абстракции как "простой человек, обычный человек" и т.п. А причем тут вопрос :>

Comment: @Пилум: it's a legal concept. If a man on the Clapham omnibus would not have gone on running 250 km through a desert should a heat wave strike, but could have otherwise, then the heat wave is indeed the kind of circumstance the op is talking about.

Comment: Quassnoi, this is mean nothing in linguistic. And there is  just  no connection here. As I said and you deleted, - their "laws" are not the laws of nature and are not the laws and facts of linguistics. And in general, there is just no connection here. About how it is just to say "опасно" - and some "people from omnibuses."

Comment: "Неподготовленный человек сказал бы, что участие в таких соревнованиях - безрассудство, " - кто и что сказал бы - относится к области гипотез... "Есть ли такое слово?"  - cо вторично описанными такими условиями, - де-факто нету. Да и что такое "обычный человек" научно не определено и неизвестно.

Comment: @megasplash: could you please provide a Russian phrase with a blank to fill with the expression you're looking for?

Comment: @Quassnoi There are couple such phrases with "..." to fill in in the UPD.

Comment: @Пилум Все верно. В UPD добавлено, что характеристика субъективная. И, скорее всего, эмоционально нагруженная.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как можно назвать обстоятельства, связанные с определенным действием, которые остановят любого человека в здравом уме от его выполнения?

Такие обстоятельства можно назвать **источником смертельной опасности**.

Про них также можно сказать, что они являются **стоп-фактором**. ("red flag", somewhat formal register)

На мой взгляд, здесь трудно подобрать эквивалентное и ходовое *назывное* словосочетание. Если ваш контекст позволяет, попробуйте выразить ту же мысль через предикат:

- Жара **гибельна**.
- Жара **обрекает на гибель**.
- Жара **не оставляет шанса**.
- Жара **представляет смертельную опасность**.

**UPD:**

> Неподготовленный человек сказал бы, что участие в таких соревнованиях - безрассудство, потому что ...

Неподготовленный человек сказал бы, что участвовать в таких соревнованиях безрассудно, потому что это чистое **самоубийство**.

**UPD 2:**

> Такие обстоятельства, в которых "обычный" человек не окажется по собственной воле.

Экстремальные?
Соответствующим существительным будет "**экстрим**".

Comment: Пожалуй, стоп-фактор выражает как раз искомый смысл. Но он ведь применяется только в области финансов?

Comment: @megasplash Не только. Например, я вполне могу сказать, что употребление наркотиков - это стоп-фактор для развития отношений с девушкой. А увольнение по статье (being fired with cause) может стать стоп-фактором для устройства на работу в другом месте. Но разумеется, это выражение не универсально, и в некоторых контекстах будет звучать очень странно.

Comment: megasplash, хотя смысл понятен, как такой составной конструкции  - оно вообще практически не применяется... :) Ну то есть это не какое-то устойчивое массовое выражение, а просто два слова через дефис... :)

Comment: megasplash, вы точно так же можете сказать - "капец-карачун" :>>

Comment: Вот оно, "чистое самоубийство" - это то, что нужно.

Comment: @megasplash или "это было бы равносильно самоубийству"; "для обычного человека бежать марафон по такой жаре — было бы равносильно самоубийству"

Comment: Igor G "стоп-фактор для развития отношений с девушкой. "   - не знаю - кто так говорит. Роботы ?

Answer (score 3):

Есть несколько способов для выражения причины отказа, как уже упоминалось, в основном, это зависит от контекста. Но наиболее точными я считаю **веские основания** и **уважительная причина**.

У него были веские основания отказаться от марафона — в пустыне стояла неимоверная жара.

In English that would be valid reason, good reason, valid excuse, reasonable excuse.

Дополнение:.. «Т.е. хочется субъективно охарактеризовать обстоятельства, **останавливающие одних, и не останавливающие других**»
Если в **этом** смысле... Это **проверка на вшивость** (испытание), англ challenge.

Comment: "веские основания и уважительная причина." - это ОЧЕНЬ абстрактно и не точно , "подходит" к вообще любому случаю, а не что-то специальное вроде того примера с пустыней :> Смертельного. :>

https://youtu.be/XPH0DGvU9Ng?t=321 "веские основания", :))))
Вообщем, слишком безэмоционально, вяло. Ну - если именно так требуется почему-то, дело другое :>

Comment: the man from the omnibus, однако... :>>> Карсон :))))))))

Comment: "Подходит к любому случаю " — исходя из формулировки вопроса, это именно и нужно, насколько я понимаю. И право иметь собственное мнение никто не отменял.

Comment: "Скорее всего - связанные с угрозой жизни и здоровья, когда выполнение подобных действий называют безрассудством." - нууу неет :) 
Ну то есть... "веская и уважительная причина" - школьник опоздал в школу, потому что автобус сломался. Хотя вообще мог бы и на такси сесть, а ? :> 

Ну то есть - ВСЕ эти случаи покрываются... а не такое вот "смертельное" там. 
Ну вообщем, я выше сказал. Это может быть, коэш, - просто это не специфический и не лучший вариант :> Вяло, абстрактно. А так и это покатит.  Может для суда какого-нибудь и лучше даж :>
https://youtu.be/l5tkDzJqhLs :>

Comment: "англ challenge." - русское "вызов".

Comment: Пилум, это «вяло», русский гораздо богаче.

Comment: что - "вяло" ? 
https://rustih.ru/fridrix-shiller-perchatka/
Это примерно так же вяло - как удар в лицо :>
Или хотя б стальной перчаткой... :>

Answer (score 0):

Во всяких там "бизнес"-случаях - *"форс-мажор", "форс-мажорные обстоятельства"*.

*"Опасность"*.
*"Угроза жизни", "опасные условия"...   "верная смерть", "смертельное окружение".*
*"Опасно для жизни"* - это даже идиоматично.

Всё больше - словосочетания.
Если одним словом... Нууууу - *"фатальность"*... :> хотя это и не очень звучит. *"Форс-мажор"* можно использовать таки.
Многое зависит от контекста.
*"Опасность", "опасности", "опасно"* - мне кажется, это лучший вариант. Насколько я понял вопрос.

*"Летальность"* :)... Но всё ж с добавлением пояснения всяко лучше будя. :> *"Летальность сей пустыни"*.

"отказаться что-либо делать, одним-двумя словами?" - *"Это слишком опасно"*. :)*"Это - летально !", "Или фатально !"* :> или *"Это смертельно !"*

*"Условия, несовместимые с жизнью"*... :> Прикольно-протокольно эдак.

Comment: Довольно много вариантов для одного ответа) Опасность, наверно, ближе всего по смыслу, но она имеет характер объективной оценки. Т.е. если жара опасная, то она опасна для всех. Даже с уточнением, что жара опасна только для неподготовленного участника, тоже будет достаточно объективно. А нужна некая субъективная и эмоционально окрашенная оценка.

Comment: Достаточно эмоционально. Что касается субъективности - вы желаете субъективности и не для всех - а приводите объективный пример...  Да и вообще вот это вот "которые остановят любого человека в здравом уме " - это требование объективности де-факто.

Comment: При желании можно поспорить. Объективные факты говорят, что сотни, возможно, тысячи человек организованно участвуют в подобных "безумствах" ежегодно, значит, не так уж и опасно. Ну а "человек в здравом уме" - это точно субъективно.

Answer (score 0):

Препятствие? «Жара стала непреодолимым препятствием к проведению марафона».

Comment: это не личный отказ, а констатация, причем - массового факта.